# Send data from adapter to next Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

How to send data from adapter to fragmnet.

[image: This is How me layout look]

Here I am using Recyclerview to show my contactlist So here is the Adapter code

**RecyclerView Adapter code :**

```
public class contactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<contactModel> getdetails =new ArrayList<contactModel>(  );
Context con;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Sendcontact sendcontact;

public contactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<contactModel> getdetails) {
    this.con = context;
    this.getdetails = getdetails;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from( con);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.contactlist, viewGroup, false );
    contactLayout layout = new contactLayout(view );
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    contactLayout layout = (contactLayout) viewHolder;
    final contactModel details = getdetails.get( i );
    layout.contactname.setText( "  "+details.getContactname() );
    layout.contactnum.setText( "  "+details.getContactnumber() );
    layout.favcheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked == true){
                String status = "true";
                String id = details.contactid;
                String favname = details.contactname;
                String favnum = details.contactnumber;
                sendcontact.OnItemclicked(id);

            }else{
                String status = "false";
                String id = details.contactid;
                String favname = details.contactname;
                String favnum = details.contactnumber;
            }
        }
    } );


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getdetails.size();
}

 public interface Sendcontact{
    void OnItemclicked(String id);
}

private class contactLayout extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView contactname, contactnum;
    CheckBox favcheck;
    public contactLayout(View view) {
        super(view);
        contactname = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.name );
        contactnum = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.phonenumber );
        favcheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById( R.id.favcheck );
    }
}
```

}

This is my First Fragment view. So whenever I check on checkbox that data should be send to my next fragment.

Here is Code from my next Fragment

**Favorite Fragment class :**

```
public class Favorite extends Fragment {
public Favorite() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false );
    return view;
}
contactAdapter.Sendcontact sendcontact = new contactAdapter.Sendcontact() {
    @Override
    public void OnItemclicked(String id) {
        Log.e( TAG, id  );
    }
};

}
```

Comment: Where do you keep the RecyclerView.Adapter instance?

Comment: Its in my first fragment @KrzysztofKubicki

Answer (score 0):

Add to your adapter callback interface:

```
private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemChecked(ContactModel model);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

and use that listener:

```
    layout.favcheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new 
         CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(listener != null)
            listener.onItemChecked(details)
    }
} );
```

there is two ways:

implement this listener in second fragment:

```
public class Contacts extends Fragment implements contactAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

    ...

    //assign listener to instance of adapter here

    // use
    @Override
    onItemChecked(ContactModel model){
    //send data to second fragment here
    }

    ...

}
```

implement this listener in first fragment:

```
public class Contacts extends Fragment implements contactAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

    ...

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)

    @Override
    onItemChecked(ContactModel model){
    //send data to second fragment here
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Can you my updated code. This is the way should i do it?

Comment: When I click on checkbox the gets crashed and this message is displayed :

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.learn.nikhil.contact.contactAdapter$Sendcontact.OnItemclicked(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

1.Make a listener class

```
public interface MyOnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}
```

2.make an object of the listener in the fragment where you want to send the update

```
public class Favorite extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    .
    .
    MyOnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener=new MyOnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {

        selected_validity=position;
        //do whatever you want here

       }
    };
    contactAdapter ContactAdapter = new contactAdapter(your_list,this,myOnItemClickListener);
    yourRecyclerview.setAdapter(ContactAdapter);

}

}
```

3.Change adapter as follows:

```
public class contactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
MyOnItemClickListener listener;
ArrayList<contactModel> getdetails =new ArrayList<contactModel>(  );
Context con;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public contactAdapter(ArrayList<contactModel> getdetails, Context context,MyOnItemClickListener listener ) {
    this.con = context;
    this.getdetails = getdetails;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from( con);
    this.listener = listener;
}


private class contactLayout extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView contactname, contactnum;
    CheckBox favcheck;
    public contactLayout(View view) {
        super(view);
        contactname = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.name );
        contactnum = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.phonenumber );
        favcheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById( R.id.favcheck );
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {


                Toast.makeText(context,"pos: "+getLayoutPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you my updated code. This is the way should i do it?

Comment: @nikhillohar i already gave you an implementation, try it and see it it works